# Identify $ \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+k)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Identify $$ f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+k)^2}.$$

Is this a known expansion of a simpler looking function? I understand that this series becomes infinite at integers.

Comment: This will end up being something like $\pi^2/\sin^2{\pi x} $.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that (see [here](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf)) for $x\not \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$\pi\cot(\pi x)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{x-k}=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{x+k}.$$
Since it is analytic you can differentiate it term by term and we obtain,
$$-\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2{(\pi x)}}=\left(\pi\cot(\pi x)\right)'=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{-1}{(x+k)^2}.$$
Finally
$$\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(x+k)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2{(\pi x)}}.$$

Comment: The verb is ['differentiate'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative)

Comment: the argument for differentiating term by term is that it converges absolutely (for $x \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, and grouping $1/(x-k)$ with $1/(x+k)$)

Comment: Yes, it is important to group this.  Conditional convergence indexed by $\mathbb Z$ needs such explanation.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Note that
>   $\ds{\left.\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + z}^{2}}\right\vert_{\ x\ \not\in\ \mathbb{Z}} = \Psi\,'\pars{z}}$ is [a well known identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.15.E1). $\ds{\Psi}$ is the *Digamma Function*.

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\mrm{f}\pars{x}} & \equiv
\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\,\,{1 \over \pars{x + k}^{2}} =
{1 \over x^{2}} + \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{1 \over \pars{k + x}^{2}} + {1 \over \pars{k - x}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\overbrace{{1 \over x^{2}} + \Psi\, '\pars{x}}^{\ds{\Psi\, '\pars{1 + x}}}\ +\ \Psi\, '\pars{-x}\qquad\pars{~Recurrence~}
\\[5mm] & =
-\pi\,\totald{\cot\pars{\pi x}}{x}\qquad
\pars{~Euler\ Reflection\ Formula~}
\\[5mm] & = \color{#f00}{\pi^{2}\csc^{2}\pars{\pi x}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the [well known summation formula](http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf) $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f\left(k\right)=-\sum\left\{ \textrm{residues of }\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)f\left(z\right)\textrm{ at }f\left(z\right)\textrm{'s poles}\right\} 
 $$ so we have to evaluate $$\underset{z=-x}{\textrm{Res}}\frac{\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)}{\left(z+x\right)^{2}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow-x}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)\right)=-\pi^{2}\csc^{2}\left(\pi x\right)$$ hence $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{\left(k+x\right)^{2}}=\color{red}{\pi^{2}\csc^{2}\left(\pi x\right)}$$ obviously if $x$ is not an integer.