Some questions about this series equal to pi over sine squared of pi z
The questions I have are relating to the proof that this equation is true
$$\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2 \pi z} =\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$$
here is a link https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/complex/notes_2014-15/08a_product_sine.pdf.
The ratio test is inconclusive, but the text I am reading says convergence is obvious. Also, it claims that the Laurent series around the pole $n=k$ has a term $$\frac{1}{(z-k)^2}$$
which I can see for the LHS but I have no idea about the RHS.
So the questions I have are: why is the series obviously convergent and how would I go about computing the first few terms of the Laurent series for the sum, assuming we don't know the given equality?
Ta! :)

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1921793/42969
